# Why is every activity suddenly giving me errors?

Tags: android, android-studio

I restarted Android Studio and now nothing works and there's errors everywhere.
It says:

```
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:207: error: Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:209: error: Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:211: error: Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:213: error: Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:216: error: Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:243: error: Attribute "paddingStart" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:245: error: Attribute "paddingEnd" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:260: error: Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:261: error: Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:263: error: Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:265: error: Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:267: error: Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:270: error: Attribute "actionModeCutDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:272: error: Attribute "actionModeCopyDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:274: error: Attribute "actionModePasteDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:276: error: Attribute "actionModeSelectAllDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:278: error: Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:280: error: Attribute "actionModeFindDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:282: error: Attribute "actionModeWebSearchDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:285: error: Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
[2014-07-31 23:46:15 - kieranmaps] C:\Users\gabby\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:290: error: Attribute "actionDropDownStyle" has already been defined
```

But I have imported appcombactv7_2 and google play services again as I closed all the projects and then reopened them to try and fix it but actually made it worse.
Now I don't know what to make of all the errors. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: looks like you have the compat library defines twice, remove one of them

Comment: if I go to project>properties>android>libraries it's only there once. Is that what you mean>

Comment: have a look at your build.gradle file in your app directory, something might have gone wrong there

Comment: The build config file?

Comment: ProjectRoot/app/build.gradle, assuming you named your application "app" (simply didn't changed what AndroidStudio suggests by default)

Comment: I don't seem to have one. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: I fixed it! I had an error in my xml! thankfully it's fixed. thanks for your help!